# Prevent 'Press ENTER' when pathogen loads but keep for other scripts

Tags: startup, plugin-managers

I have pathogen setup however when it finishes loading I have to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as shown in this screen shot.
[image]

Is there a way how to disable the 'Press Enter or type command to continue' prompt but keep it when other shell scripts are run usng the `.vimrc` file or another method?

I have had a look at [How can I suppress the "press enter" prompt when opening files in diff mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/771/how-can-i-suppress-the-press-enter-prompt-when-opening-files-in-diff-mode) however the answer looks like it disables the prompt for all scripts when I want it disabled **only** when pathogen loads.

Comment: The only think in my vimrc file for pathogen is `execute pathogen#infect()` and it does not ask me to hit `enter`. Are you invoking it differently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the `call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()` line in your vimrc to `call pathogen#infect()`, as the message suggests.

Comment: Beat me to it :-)

Comment: Missed that message it gave me!

Comment: You may have escaped the `Press ENTER` gremlin for now, but sooner or later he will be back.  When that happens, check out `:h press-enter` for some tips to avoid him!