# Vim is displaying some info and "Press ENTER ..." when I open a file

Tags: load, statusline, file-operations

From time to time I see something like in the status bar when I open a file:

```
"Gemfile" 112L, 2941C
"Gemfile" 112 lines --62%--
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Where is it coming from? How to disable it forever?

This is seriously getting out of hand, I am editing wrong lines in files because when I switch to the file it is off by one line.

**Update**

When multiple files are opened in buffers and you bring Vim to foreground especially after some changes like `git merge` Vim seem to reload files.

Settings `cmdheight` to 2 doesn't help because there might be more messages. This is what I just had after merge:

```
NORMAL  +3 ~9 departments  ... STATUS BAR
"app/assets/stylesheets/_menu.sass.erb" 144L, 3372C
"app/assets/stylesheets/_users.sass" 120L, 2110C
"spec/factories/users.rb" 19L, 469C
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

There should be a way to get rid of this.

Comment: That *looks* like the information vim normally prints when loading a file, though it's interesting it's being printed twice. Does it still happen when you run with -u NONE?

Comment: I don't think it is supposed to wait for me to press Enter as well. No, it's some plugin I think. Guess have to find out what's causing it. The problem is - I don't see that every time.

Comment: The "press enter" prompt makes sense; it will do that when there is more text to display than would fit, as there is in this case since its displaying a bunch of extra info. See :help press-enter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is controlled with the `shortmess` option. In particular, you probably want to set the `O` (upper-case o) flag with `set shortmess+=O`.

```
O     message for reading a file overwrites any previous message.
      Also for quickfix message (e.g., ":cn").
```

Note that this is included in the Vim default, which is `filnxtToO`. So I think you either added this to your vimrc some time in the past and forgot about it, or some plugin is resetting it. In [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/771/51) you can find some tips on how to figure out where this is being reset.

Also see [`:help 'shortmess'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shm%27). And [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/771/51) is almost exactly the same.

Comment: ........... eh?

Comment: @markling Eh, what?

Answer (score 2):

So I kind of alleviated it by using

```
:set cmdheight=2
```

But that is weak sause and I don't think should be the answer.

**Update** Yep, the next day I had 3 files changed and it asked me to press enter again.

Comment: I think that use 3 is better, because sometimes more than 2 lines are shown. For me many times xD

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer from @Matin Tournoij. For me, `set shm+=O` didn't work, however, `set shm+=F` works.

The help information for this option:

> ```
> F don't give the file info when editing a file, 
> like `:silent` was used for the command; 
> note that this also affects messages from autocommands
> ```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!